# How can I target a element inside h2

Tags: css

I can't figure out how to style an H2 link in css. I've tried everything. IHow I can I target the link in an h2 element?

```
<div id="post-225" class="post-225 post type-post sticky hentry category-rugby-world-cup tag-land-rover-rugby-world-cup-2011-rugby-world-cup-2015-land-rover-rugby">
    <h2><a href="http://blog.landrover.com/events/rugby-world-cup/england-rugby-squad-vs-media-driving-challenge-day" title="Permalink to England Rugby Squad vs. Media Driving Challenge Day" rel="bookmark">England Rugby Squad vs. Media Driving Challenge Day</a></h2>
```

I need to make the headline of this sticky post white:

http://blog.landrover.com/

I've tried .sticky h2 a {color:white;} but without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.sticky h2 a {color:white;}` is being overridden by the main style:

```
#content h2 a {
color: #4C4C4C;
}
```

To target the specific h2 of the sticky class, use:

```
#content .sticky h2 a{
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: @Dan, your answer is correct in that [specificity rules](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) are being applied which gives the `#content h2 a` more weight and therefore more importance than the less specific `.sticky h2 a` rule. However I would not recommend using a`.whiteheading` class name as it is not semantically useful. Please see [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames) for reasons why.

Comment: @andyb, You are correct, however the question was how to make the h2 white. All @Jonathan has to do is target the child of the .sticky to achieve what he wants: #content .sticky h2 a or something alike.

Comment: thanks, I used this and it worked #content .sticky h2 a{
 color:white;
}

Comment: @Dan I would have up-voted your answer if the advice was semantically correct. Just answering the question might not get as many up-votes as explaining what is going wrong :)

Comment: @andyb, Totally understand and will take that in to consideration for next time. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do

```
#content .sticky h2 a { color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is anyone trying these suggestions beforehand? Nothing seems to work for me because the font replacement on the site is not working correctly. I'm getting a `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff.` error in Chrome 11. Maybe if that is fixed, simply adding

```
.sticky h2 a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

should work.

Comment: When I was trying the solution out in Firebug and Chrome developer, it wasn't updating the colour because of the font substitution however @Jonanthan said the solution worked. Not sure why it wasn't showing up on our end =S

Comment: it uses cufon, which means you can't change on the fly ie. via Firebug or web inspector.  You'd have to change it in the CSS, then reload the page.